# Show protocols of packets captured and saved in a .pcap with scapy on python

Tags: python, protocols, analysis, pcap, scapy

I am capturing live air WiFi traffic and saving **only the headers** of the packets captures in a `.pcap` file.
Is it possible to find out what protocols have been used on the whole capture? If yes, how can I keep track of the number of packets under every protocol found?

I've found a lot of info on injecting packets with Scapy but not on analyzing.

So far I've tried:

```
from scapy.all import * # import scapy package
from scapy.utils import rdpcap # import module for loading pcaps
pkts = rdpcap("./traffic/capture20131120-001.pcap") # load pcap
pkts.summary(lambda(r): r.sprintf("%Dot11.proto%")) # protocol?
print -(256-ord(pkts[24].notdecoded[-4:-3])) # signal strength of packet 24
```

Seems like `pkts.summary(lambda(r): r.sprintf("%Dot11.proto%"))` returns `0L` and I don't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Scapy does not support very many protocols, so it's great for some tasks, but not others. Using `pyshark` instead (a Python wrapper for Wireshark), there are many more supported protocols.

---

Using Scapy:

```
from scapy.all import *

def process_with_scapy(fileName):
    protocol_count = {}

    pcap_data = rdpcap(fileName)
    sessions = pcap_data.sessions()
    for session in sessions:
        for packet in sessions[session]:
            for i in range(len(packet.layers())):
                layer = packet.getlayer(i)
                protocol = layer.name

                # Count the number of occurences for each protocol type
                if protocol not in protocol_count: protocol_count[protocol] = 1
                else: protocol_count[protocol] += 1

    # Sort the dictionary in descending order
    protocol_count = dict(sorted(protocol_count.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
    
    # Print the output
    for protocol in protocol_count:
        print(f'{protocol_count[protocol]} packets have layer "{protocol}"')

process_with_scapy('./traffic/capture20131120-001.pcap')
```

Documentation:
https://readthedocs.org/projects/scapy/downloads/pdf/latest

---

Using PyShark (slower but more supported):

```
import pyshark

def process_with_pyshark(fileName):
    protocol_count = {}

    pcap_data = pyshark.FileCapture(fileName)
    for packet in pcap_data:
        for layer in packet:
            protocol = layer.layer_name

            # Count the number of occurences for each protocol type
            if protocol not in protocol_count: protocol_count[protocol] = 1
            else: protocol_count[protocol] += 1

    # Sort the dictionary in descending order
    protocol_count = dict(sorted(protocol_count.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))

    # Print the output
    for protocol in protocol_count:
        print(f'{protocol_count[protocol]} packets have layer "{protocol}"')


process_with_pyshark('./traffic/capture20131120-001.pcap')
```

- For information on a specific protocol:
  https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/
- The source code for a specific protocol dissector can also sometimes be useful:
  https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/tree/master/epan/dissectors